# Greyed-out save to SD card button issue on LG Optimus S

Tags: android, lg, optimus

Looking for suggestions for further troubleshooting on this (or a fix, if someone actually has one).  App (Dream Journal Pro) has been out there for a few months, has move to SD functionality for 2.2 phones, works fine on my development EVO, and hundreds of other users have reported no issues with that functionality.  User reported today that she only gets the greyed out move to SD card button with this app on her LG Optimus S.  Already checked/tried:

Uninstalled and reinstalled app to no effect.

18MB free on phone and 400+ MB free on SD card (app is 112kb installed).

Tried Apps2SD with no luck.

Demo version of app (Dream Journal Demo) is the same code base, with the exception of a 5 record limit;  demo saves to SD card without issue for this user.

Phone is stock, not rooted.

App is being installed from Android Marketplace, and user is in US.

Other apps save to SD card without issue on this phone for this user.

I know this isn't a code question, but I'm stumped as to how to troubleshoot this further for this user, as there are no error messages, just the greyed-out save to SD button.

Any and all suggestions appreciated -

Comment: Just got a user with the same issue. It started after phone got the Gingerbread update.  Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Never did.  On my list of things to check is the fact that I'm still using the old, ever-soon-to-be-deprecated licensing, and need to add code to handle the new licensing routines.  I believe the old licensing you could add when uploading an app requires certain SD card permissions and some other things which might cause issues such as this one.